# How to list only first directories in zip file?

Tags: linux, bash, shell

`unzip -l` show all directory and sub-directories/files.

I'd like to list only the first directory structure insize a zip file, something like `-maxdepth 1` of `find` command.

Is there some way to do it without a entire script?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At least with `UnZip 6.00` in Debian based distros, you can use the `-x` option with wildcards as described in `man unzip`:

> ```
> [-x xfile(s)]
>       An optional list of archive members to be excluded from process‐
>       ing.   Since  wildcard characters normally match (`/') directory
>       separators (for exceptions see the option -W), this  option  may
>       be  used  to  exclude any files that are in subdirectories.  For
>       example, ``unzip foo *.[ch] -x */*'' would extract all C  source
>       files  in  the  main  directory, but none in any subdirectories.
>       Without the -x option, all C source  files  in  all  directories
>       within the zipfile would be extracted.
> ```

So for example, given

```
$ unzip -l dir
Archive:  dir.zip
  Length      Date    Time    Name
---------  ---------- -----   ----
        0  2023-03-11 07:57   dir/
       24  2023-03-11 12:50   dir/file
     1464  2023-03-04 12:51   dir/input.csv
      187  2023-03-06 09:03   dir/input
        0  2023-02-28 10:25   dir/subdir3/
        0  2023-02-28 10:25   dir/subdir3/Files.txt
       55  2023-02-28 10:51   dir/file2
       26  2023-03-10 20:00   dir/utf-16BE.txt
        0  2023-02-28 10:25   dir/subdir2/
        0  2023-02-28 10:25   dir/subdir2/File.txt
        0  2023-02-28 10:25   dir/subdir1/
        0  2023-02-28 10:25   dir/subdir1/file.txt
      585  2023-03-01 06:54   dir/source.CSV
      115  2023-02-28 10:50   dir/file1
      211  2023-03-10 09:01   dir/01-netcfg.yaml
---------                     -------
     2667                     15 files
```

then

```
$ unzip -l dir -x '*/*/*'
Archive:  dir.zip
  Length      Date    Time    Name
---------  ---------- -----   ----
        0  2023-03-11 07:57   dir/
       24  2023-03-11 12:50   dir/file
     1464  2023-03-04 12:51   dir/input.csv
      187  2023-03-06 09:03   dir/input
       55  2023-02-28 10:51   dir/file2
       26  2023-03-10 20:00   dir/utf-16BE.txt
      585  2023-03-01 06:54   dir/source.CSV
      115  2023-02-28 10:50   dir/file1
      211  2023-03-10 09:01   dir/01-netcfg.yaml
---------                     -------
     2667                     9 files
```

Comment: it has worked in Oracle Linux 7!

Answer (score 0):

##### Like this, in a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) way:

```
curl -s https://gist.githubusercontent.com/sputnick-dev/1d2303e5fb75af8792f828ff33c127af/raw/e42cd4f56ce1b430752269cff2571342b19eb58a/gistfile1.txt | bash
cd /tmp
zip -r rand_dirs.zip rand_dirs
unzip -l rand_dirs.zip |
    grep -oP '^\s+\d+\s+\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}\s+\d{2}:\d{2}\s+\K[^/]+/[^/]+' |
    sort -u
```

##### Output

```
rand_dirs/Yqol
rand_dirs/yT3oVke
rand_dirs/yt7p
rand_dirs/z
rand_dirs/z8Tx
rand_dirs/ZaQ7cE
rand_dirs/zeWgeCr8RbS
rand_dirs/zVf4
[...]
```